# No Grand Total when Conditionally Format Cell Background Color Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have successfully formatted the cells to show specific colors to the cells but now when I add grand total, it messes up the whole format. It looks like to me that for grand total its unable to total the values instead it just throw bunch of value from above rows.

Below is how it looks like with no grand total:

[image]

This is how it looks like after when I add grand total:

[image]

I am looking to have nice view like first photo but with the grand total. Please suggest if that something is possible.

Comment: Can you please share your file in drive? What is min(number if records) doing on size in marks card? It seems you have overcomplicated the simple view.

Comment: I also suggest that instead of asking how to simplify the things you should simply ask how to build the view!

Comment: What happens if you change the mark type to Square? It looks like the Grand Total is summing your bars and it looks confusing.